# Wrapping text in relative layout inside linear layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout for items in my listview. Every item I use in my list view uses this layout. the code for layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/view">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_header"
        style="@style/category_list_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_header"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:text="some text"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

the text i populate to the textview with id 'messages_list_element_textview_header' does not wrap. the textview I am using below this('messages_list_element_textview_view') is for displaying dates so I would not like to wrap it.

Could someone please advise how I can get the 'messages_list_element_textview_header' to wrap.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fill_parent`

(deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher)

Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in. It's roughly equivalent of setting the dockstyle of a Windows Form Control to Fill.

Setting a top level layout or control to fill_parent will force it to take up the whole screen.

```
wrap_content
```

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

```
wrap_content
```

will be adjustable based on your text size and amount of text. It is always preferable. Otherwise you can set the `dp` like `60dp` increase or decrease based on your need

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/view">


  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_header"
        style="@style/category_list_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_header"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:text="some text"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot set a fixed height as the textview outside the relative layout is wrapping as needed. I would not like any effect to the textview outside the relative layout.

Comment: @BountyHunter Make your parent layout as RelativeLayout and give layout_below for your TextView which is outside the Layout

Comment: that didnt help much. The entire screen goes blank on using this code

Answer (score 0):

To nest layouts, there must be a proper indentation. Your indentation has a mistake. The outermost Linear Layout must wrap the Relative Layout(the relative should be 1 tab space away).